# Need to use contents of current row from mysql table to print using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

table.jsp:

```
<%
//jsp prog for database connection

String query="SELECT total,gtotal from allinvoice";
statement=conn.createStatement();
resultset=statement.executeQuery(query);

if(resultset.next()){ %>
<br><br>
<table class="center" cellpadding="7" border="1" style="background-color:  #F0F0FC;" >
<tr><th align="left" >Total</th><th><%= resultset.getDouble(1) %></th></tr>
<%long i=resultset.getInt(15); %>
<tr><th colspan="2">Grand Total</th><th><%= resultset.getInt(2) %></th>    </tr>
```

`
I have created a table with few columns which looks like this:

[image]

Now when generate button is clicked jsp should print data of its respective row. I am using if() to print result set, but every i click generate it is printing only first row.the relevant code is table.jsp .please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide relevant code?

Comment: hey i have updated my question. pls go through my code

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in there. Can you post the fragment of code related to the generate button and how you process the request?  I suspect something might be wrong there

Comment: `<%while(resultset.next()){ %>  <TD> <%= resultset.getDouble(1) %></TD>
    <TD> <%= resultset.getInt(2) %></TD>
    <TD> <%= resultset.getString(3) %></TD>

    <TD>                 <ul  style="list-style: none;"><li style="float: center;"><a href="http://localhost/profile/hclinvgen.jsp"><button type="button">Generate</button></a></li></ul>
</TD>
         
            </TR>
                <%
                }`

Comment: I was referring to the code to process the request triggered by the "generate" button, servlet code basically. The easiest thing to do would be adding code to your original post

Comment: this is the loop am using to for displaying table.along with generate button...

Comment: the generate button triggers the code included question/.

Comment: If that is the case the issue might be the lack of a where clause in your query

Comment: other than manual insertion of where clause ,is there any way to make it automatically retrieve that particular row of data.

Comment: You still have to provide a where clause with a parameter that identifies the specific row: it won't happen automatically just because you clicked the generate button on that row. Hope that makes sense

Comment: A solution could be to create a form around the generate button with a hidden input field for each row and retrieve the hidden field as a request parameter to use in the where clause of your db query

Comment: seems to be a bit tedious way,but i think it is also the only way..thanks for the assist :)

Comment: Hope that'll help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the issue lies in this line

```
String query="SELECT total,gtotal from allinvoice";
```

Since in your query there is not a `where` clause every row will be retrieved from the *allinvoice* table. Unless your table contains only one row you will not get a specific entry.

Therefore when the `if` block represented below will execute, it will only fetch the first row in the table

```
if(resultset.next()) {
    // code...
}
```

You want to have something like this:

```
String query="SELECT total,gtotal from allinvoice where <condition here>";
```

Where the *condition here* uniquely identifies each row in the table.

Comment: but the where clause displays all rows and i don't want that...is there any way to make it automatically retrieve respective row's data

Comment: @pradyu The where clause will allow you to select a specific row or a specific set of rows, which (if I understood the issue) is exactly what you want